# How to delete a record for a text file using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a pipe delimited text file with header row. In some cases the file has no records but it has header row and a set of `||||||` on the second row (In these cases file has only two rows header and the pipe characters)
In a batch file I would like to check the second record (row) of the pipe delimited test file and if it starts with `|` then delete the row and save the file (keep just the header row)

How can we do this with CMD commands in a batch file?

Comment: Are you **really** using MS-DOS or are you talking about the command line in Windows?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
find /v "||||||" <"inputfilename" >"outputfilename"
```

should accomplish that task quite nicely. It simply finds the lines in the file that do *not* contain the pipe-string.

Comment: or to take `if it starts with |` literally: `findstr /vb "|"` (Doesn't work in DOS, but I guess it's `cmd`)